# Zurb foundation modal with ajax (rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, zurb-foundation

I have a modal form in which I select a option from a drop down and add some text to a text area.

The problem is when ever a user clicks on a finalized meeting link an ajax call is generated and it call the get_meeting method. When this method finishes it call a page "get_meeting.js.erb" in which I am using js to open the modal. but when ever it open the modal it does not load the the select menu and the text area but on the modal the js is written. Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

**finalized link to modal and ajax call**

```
<li><a href="/requests/get_meetings?id=<%= request._id %>" data-reveal-id="form-details-modal-lbms"  class="finalize_request" data-remote="true" id="<%= request._id %>" data-reveal-ajax="true"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Finalize</a></li>
```

**get-meeting function**

```
 # GET /requests/get_meetings
  def get_meetings
    @id = params[:id]

  end
```

**get_meeting.js.erb**

```
$('#form-details-modal-lbms').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem use `link_to` helper and `remote` option. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to) is example.

Comment: I am using the remote option but just with simple html